# How can I temporarily block network traffic for a specific windows process?

Tags: windows-xp, process

Windows XP / Windows 7

I'd like to understand how a specific windows process (from a third-party vendor) behaves when it's selectively blocked from communicating on a network (by say, an overzealous software firewall).  Is there a free (and ideally light-weight) tool I can use to do this?  I don't want to block ALL network connectivity on the user workstation - just connection attempts from a specific process.

Comment: Why the -1? This pertains to enterprise support / analysis for a user workstation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using Windows Firewall.
You can set some restrictions based on application instead than on in/out ports.

Here you can find a nice tutorial:
http://www.technipages.com/blockunblock-programs-in-windows-firewall

Regards